# SSH key management in big and mixed environments (Linux)

Tags: linux, ssh-keys, user-management, configuration-managment

In every company I worked at it was always pain in the ass to manage ssh keys. We had different ways of managing them. But mostly it were some CM systems like puppet/chef/ansible or just manual copy of keys or even some ugly bash scripts :D

Also heard that some people use LDAP or any DB as ssh key store. But still you need some additional automation over here like some CM tool to put/delete key on server.

So the question is, is there some nice and modern way of doing it that I don't know? How big IT companies (like google or facebook etc) are handling keys?

Comment: I voted to close as opinion based. You largely answered your own question with Puppet/Chef/LDAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Meta: IMO this question is not opinion-based.)

If you're on fairly modern Linux/Unix versions with a fairly recent OpenSSH you can use OpenSSH certificates. If you want kind of "ticket" feeling with MFA you can issue temporary OpenSSH certificates.

The point with OpenSSH certs is that the only thing needed to be installed at sshd's side is the SSH-CA's public key referenced with directive [TrustedUserCAKeys in sshd_config](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#TrustedUserCAKeys).

With the directives [AuthorizedPrincipals*](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand) you can also accept a set of principal names (basically the user names) in OpenSSH certificates for another local user account.

OpenSSH certificates are not X.509 certificates, they have a different format specified in the source tree document [PROTOCOL.certkeys](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.certkeys).

You will find several web pages how to use [ssh-keygen](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1) to sign public keys with a SSH-CA (e.g. [Using SSH certificates](https://www.sweharris.org/post/2016-10-30-ssh-certs/)).

I've implemented such a small SSH-CA for a customer running as a web service to issue temporary user certificates based on multi-factor authentication (LDAP and OTP).

You will find several open source implementations in the usual places. I deliberately do not give a list here, because after reviewing a couple of them I've implemented my own and thus do not want to endorse a particular implementation. This does not mean that those implementations do not work. They just did not meet my specific customer requirements.

Caveat:

Currently it only works with *OpenSSH* or *libssh* at the client-side. *putty* does not support this yet. Also there is no support in network devices and other special appliances.

P.S.: Still I'd recommend to use a decent LDAP based user management which will give you more you need.

Comment: Interesting. Thx!

Comment: Accept the answer?